# Change the text of the publish button to Save

Tags: publish, block-editor, buttons

I am trying to change the text of the publish button to save

```php
function change_publish_button( $translation, $text ) {

    if ( $text == 'Publish' )
        return 'Save';

    return $translation;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_publish_button', 10, 2 );
```

I am trying to run the above code but it doesn't change the text of the publish button, can anyone please tell what is wrong with this code or suggest any new method. Thanks in advance

Update 
I want to change the publish button shown in the figure below.
[image]

Comment: The original text has a "..." after it, so $text isn't `Publish`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Even after changing it to "..." it doesn't work.

Comment: It's probably a single ellipsis character. Just inspect it in the browser and copy the exact text.

Comment: note that the filter is for PHP based translations, Gutenberg has JS based translations, this will require a JS based solution

Answer (score 0):

Put below code into your theme **functions.php** and try

```
function change_publish_button( $translation, $text ) {

    if ( $text == 'Publish...' )     // Your button text
        $text = 'Save';

    return $text;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_publish_button', 10, 2 );
```

This one is worked for me

[image]

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function translate_publish( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain ) {
    if( stripos( $untranslated_text, 'Publish' ) !== FALSE ) {
        $translated_text = str_ireplace( 'Publish', 'Save', $untranslated_text ) ;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
if(is_admin()){
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'translate_publish', 99, 3 );
}
```

Comment: it does work for the publish to save on the list of posts under the date option but it doesn't change the text of the button.

Comment: Which other button are you talking about?

Comment: I have updated the image, the publish button which is next to the preview button