# How to change the text of Publish Button

Tags: jquery, metabox, buttons

I am trying to change the text of the publish button to save.
I could change the text.

BUT, When I click Status Edit button and OK button, it change "Publish".

How can I fix this?

### [image: change publish to save]
[image: when I click the edit status button]

This is what I tried

1. [Change the text of the publish button to Save](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/327817/change-the-text-of-the-publish-button-to-save)
2. 

```
function change_button_text(){
        echo "<script>
                 jQuery(document).ready( function() {        
                    jQuery( 'input[id=\"publish\"]' ).val('save');
                });
}
add_action('admin_head-post.php', 'change_button_text');
add_action('admin_head-post-new.php', 'change_button_text');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to change **Publish** button's text to **Save** even after editing Post Status.
Do not forget: Clicking **OK** or **Cancel** buttons when editing Post Status will change Publish button's text. This happens also when editing Post Visibility and Publish time. I used setTimeout() to postpone changing Publish button's text after Post status, visibility and time edited.

```php
function change_button_text(){
    echo "<script>
        jQuery(document).ready( function() {        
            jQuery('input[id=\"publish\"]').val('Save');
            jQuery('.save-post-status').click(change_on_post_status_visibilty_time_edit);
            jQuery('.cancel-post-status').click(change_on_post_status_visibilty_time_edit);
            jQuery('.save-post-visibility').click(change_on_post_status_visibilty_time_edit);
            jQuery('.cancel-post-visibility').click(change_on_post_status_visibilty_time_edit);
            jQuery('.save-timestamp').click(change_on_post_status_visibilty_time_edit);
            jQuery('.cancel-timestamp').click(change_on_post_status_visibilty_time_edit);
        });
        
        function change_on_post_status_visibilty_time_edit(){
            setTimeout( function() {jQuery( 'input[id=\"publish\"]' ).val('Save')}, 100);
        };
        
        </script>";
}

add_action('admin_head-post.php', 'change_button_text');
add_action('admin_head-post-new.php', 'change_button_text');
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly!!

Comment: Glad it was helpful.